# What is the most efficient way to deal with methods that return variable length results into a fixed buffer?

Tags: c#, .net

I am using c# 4.0 and every so often I come across a method in the .NET Common Library, or some other library, that has a signature like the following (e.g. [Socket.Receive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.receive.aspx), [Stream.Read](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.read.aspx), etc)

```
int DoSomethingSuperClever(byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
```

The intention is always that you pass it in a buffer and it fills that buffer up to the maximum number of bytes you specify in the count argument (from the given offset) and returns exactly how many bytes it has really managed to fill in.

This is my, super naive, way of dealing with this situation:

```
var data = new byte[0];
var buffer = new byte[1024];
int read;

while ((read = something.DoSomethingSuperClever(buffer,
                                                0,
                                                buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    int origLength = data.Length;
    var temp = new byte[origLength + read];
    Array.Copy(data, temp, data.Length);
    Array.Copy(buffer, 0, temp, origLength, read);
    data = temp;
}

return data;
```

I think that is pretty rubbish because of all the array creations but it does the job correctly at least I suppose.

I wondered about having a `List<byte>`, adding to it then doing [ToArray](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb298736.aspx) at the end...

Of course, I cannot just call [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx%5D) because then if read was less than the length of the buffer I would get junk appended (as [AddRange](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/z883w3dc%28v=vs.80%29.aspx%5D) doesn't accept a length argument it will always add the entire collection).  So then I think to go with that approach I would end up with a for loop and loads of [Add](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/3wcytfd1%28v=vs.80%29) calls but surely that is even worse than the array copy isn't it?

So, experts, what is the most efficient way that I should be dealing with these types of calls?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd use a `MemoryStream` instead of a `byte[]`:

```
var data = new MemoryStream();
var buffer = new byte[1024];
int read = 0;

while ((read = something.DoSomethingSuperClever(buffer,
                                                0,
                                                buffer.Length) > 0)
{
    data.Write(buffer, 0, read);
}

return data.ToArray();
```

Depending on the source of your `something` object you might want to adjust the buffer size to be more efficient.

Comment: it should be `data.Write(buffer, 0, read);`. No need for the `start` variable.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: what yould happen with your suggestion if the loop runs more than one time?

Comment: It would work correctly ;-) Note: The second parameter of `MemoryStream.Write` is the offset in the first parameter (`buffer`) and NOT in the MemoryStream.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: your right! Messed it up the first time. Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

> So, experts, what is the most efficient way that I should be dealing with these types of calls?

Well one *simple* way is to write it all to a `MemoryStream` a chunk at a time, then use [`MemoryStream.ToArray`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray.aspx). Let it deal with buffer resizing etc.

```
MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream();
while ((read = something.DoSomethingSuperClever(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    ms.Write(buffer, 0, read);
}
return ms.ToArray();
```

(I would typically have a bigger buffer than 1K, by the way. Obviously it depends on your use case, but I'd normally default to 8, 16 or 32K.)

Comment: Thanks Jon - yeah, I stuck in the first number that came into my head for that buffer size (I wonder why that was 1024 - probably a traumatic experience from childhood).

Comment: @kmp: The MemoryStream automatically advances its internal position after the Write operation. The 0 tells the `Write` method at which position it should start reading the data from `buffer`.

Comment: Thanks, yeah, I just noticed that comment below!